# HTML/CSS How to apply CSS to "a" with custom data attribute?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I already know how to apply CSS to custom data attributes but in my case it just doesn't seem to work. I don't want to select by class but by data-store attribute.

HTML

```
<a data-store="{&quot;dialogURI&quot;:&quot;\/messages\/compose\/dialog\/&quot;}" href="#"></a>
```

CSS

```
[data-store=" {&quot;dialogURI&quot;:&quot;\/messages\/compose\/dialog\/&quot;}"]{
position:fixed!important;
bottom:0px!important;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to target it by data-store, the actual attribute, or the attribute + the value ?

Comment: @gerdi Everything that is inside the data-store attribute.

Comment: You might need to use an [alternative rel selector](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Can't I select it with the data-store attr?

Comment: yeah .. sorry i did not word that correctly. The selectors still apply to a data- attribute so $= , ~= , |= should all still work for [data-store] . But it might not be what you are looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&quot;`s you see in the HTML attribute are character references for double quotes. They are represented in a CSS attribute selector as literal double quotes, not the HTML entities, since HTML entities pertain to HTML only. Since the value contains double quotes, use single quotes to delimit the value in your attribute selector so you don't have to escape the double quotes *in* the value.

The backslashes in the attribute value need to be escaped, so `\` becomes `\\`.

There is also a wayward leading space in your attribute selector that should be removed.

Hence:

```
[data-store='{"dialogURI":"\\/messages\\/compose\\/dialog\\/"}'] {
position:fixed!important;
bottom:0px!important;
}
```

As mentioned by others, if the element has a class and you can identify that element using that class and some context, it's a better idea to do that. However, the element in question may not always appear in the same context or may not be the only one with the class, and you don't always have control over the markup — so there is nothing wrong with using an attribute selector if you don't have any other options.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the class? Selecting by data attribute is a very bad idea, especially in that form.

```
.hello {
    position: fixed !important;
    bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

Btw, you should try to avoid !important...

Also look at

```
~=
```

in your css. It allows spaces in the rel attribute.

Comment: This does not answer the question .. comment maybe?

Comment: it does answer the question. it´s a much better solution instead of using that weird selector that will only lead to problems. selecting by data attribute is a very bad idea.

Comment: I dont want to argue about this but if you can refer the the title of the question ... it does not

Comment: ok, but you should be open to different solutions for a problem ;) - especially if they are much better.

Comment: Yeah for sure .. I think your solution will work and is probably a much better way to solve what difficulties he is having . However for reference it might be confusing if someone else is searching for answers

Comment: anyway, downvotes should only be used for bad and low quality answers and off topic answers. just saying, it´s of course your decision. if someone else is searching for the answer, he will find my answer very helpful too and hopefully avoid selecting by data attribute.

Comment: If I wanted to it that way I would not have come here on SO. It's because of some strict reasons that I am forced to select it via the data-store attribute. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: i understand that, there´s just no reason to do this. you can always use another additional class. it´s a DATA attribute, not a style attribute :) - you did come here for a GOOD solution, right? ;)