# Escaped HTML Entities in attribute selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-entities

I have code similar to this:

```css
div[data-stuff="&quot;stuff"] {
 font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div data-stuff="&quot;stuff">Stuff</div>
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a way to fix it without removing the quotation mark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place a backslash before the actual character to escape it in CSS:

```css
div[data-stuff="\"stuff"] {
 font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div data-stuff="&quot;stuff">Stuff</div>
```

Or if you don't want to do that, simply wrap your attribute value in single quotes instead of double quotes:

```css
div[data-stuff='"stuff'] {
 font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div data-stuff="&quot;stuff">Stuff</div>
```

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316334/html-css-how-to-apply-css-to-a-with-custom-data-attribute